# Return an edgelist from second degree query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to export an edgelist from a second degree query without using two match clauses.

I've written a query that creates the output I need but it requires searching the graph twice and reading in my matching criteria from a csv twice.

Here's my current working query:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query('LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \'file:///degree0.csv\' as pg_pap
MATCH (n:paper{paper_id:pg_pap.`paper_id`})<-[:REFERENCES]-(m:paper)
RETURN n.paper_id AS From , m.paper_id AS To
UNION ALL
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \'file:///degree0.csv\' as pg_pap
MATCH (n:paper{paper_id:pg_pap.`paper_id`})<-[:REFERENCES]-(m:paper)<-[:REFERENCES]-(o:paper)
RETURN m.paper_id AS From, o.paper_id AS To
', 'edge.csv', {})
;
```

This is the behavior I want but obviously with two `MATCH` clauses and two `LOAD CSV` statements the performance is not great. I tried writing something with a path match like this:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query('LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \'file:///degree0.csv\' as pg_pap
MATCH p=(n:paper{paper_id:pg_pap.`paper_id`})<-[:REFERENCES]-(m:paper)<-[:REFERENCES]-(o:paper)
UNWIND (nodes(p)) as nodes
RETURN nodes.paper_id', 'edge.csv', {})
;
```

But this just returns a single column of ID's without generating the edge list.

Is there a way I can write a query with a single `LOAD CSV` and a single `MATCH` clause and still return a unified edgelist for the network?

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (n:paper{paper_id:pg_pap.`paper_id`})<-[:REFERENCES]-(m:paper)
WITH
  COLLECT({from: n, to: m}) AS data1,
  [(m)<-[:REFERENCES]-(o:paper) | {from: m, to: o}] AS data2
UNWIND (data1 + data2) AS data
RETURN DISTINCT data;
```

The query collects all `m/n` pairs in `data1`, all `m/o` pairs that exist in `data2`. Then it unwinds the combination of `data1` and `data2` in order to return `DISTINCT` pairs of papers.